# What's the benefits of using sub-section in Assembly code?

Tags: assembly, linker, sections

As noted in [Using as](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_mono/as.html#SEC119), there are two main benefits of using the subsection:

1. Group the objects together even though they are not contiguous in the assembler source code. such as `.text 0 ...OTHERCODE... .text 0`
2. Separate objects even though they are in the same section. such as `.text 0 .text 1`

Let's imagine there is no the concept of subsection:

1. For 1, I think just put them in the same section would be OK, like `.text ...OTHERCODE... .text`, the code would be grouped together even there are OTHERCODE.
2. For 2, I think just using a new section would be ok, like `.text .newtext`.

So what's the true benefits of designing a `subsection` concept in the Assembly code?

Comment: To put things adjacent to each other if they're all in `.text`, you'd have to put everything into on large `.asm` or `.S` file, with things you want all in the same page actually next to each other in source order.  Being scattered around throughout `.text` doesn't help keep rarely used or startup-only code in the same page that doesn't need to stay hot in the iTLB, for example.  (Or not even paged in from disk most of the time; it can get evicted if no code in that page has run for a long time.)

Comment: Switching between `.data` and `.code` allows to **keep the data close to the code** which manipulates with it. This makes the assembler source text more comprehencible.
   
Using sub-sections also allows to define structured data at one place in asm source, and toss the data into subsections at asm-time. Data in such subsection can be effectively searched with `REPNE SCAS` at run-time, as illustrated in this example of [asm database](https://euroassembler.eu/prowin32/euroconv.htm#Tables).

Comment: It's useful for readability, for one. But more importantly, often these sections need to occupy a specific area in the CPU's address space. The assembler typically handles that for you, putting them in the appropriate location for the hardware you're developing for.